# Default to browse tab instead of edit tab on NewForm.aspx

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, office-365

Ive had a look back over previous questions regarding this but cant seem to see a solution for sharepoint online/ 365.

Basically we have a page that the end user uses to log a request and we would rather when landing on the page, the tab would default to the browse tab instead of edit. No need to hide the whole ribbon, all we need is for it to just default to Browse

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are couple of ways to show the default tab.

1. Using query string:
   http://SiteUrl/page.aspx?**InitialTabID=Ribbon.Read**
2. Update the tab using client side script. Check this out : http://sharepoint247.wordpress.com/2013/05/24/javascript-to-hide-or-select-specific-tabs-in-sharepoint-ribbon/

Comment: Thanks that worked great, opted for the client side script as i already have a query string added to the end of the URL to redirect to another page once the form is filled in, im guessing you cant have two of these?

Comment: You can use both solution at a same time. The output will be same. I prefer javascript solution as user may go to the page without querystring parameter.